# How to access beans in across different xml files

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have three xml files in my spring hibernate app

Spring-Security.xml

```
<security:authentication-manager>
            <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">

            </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.vaannila.service.CustomUserDetailsService" >

     </bean>
```

hibernate-context.xml

`enter code here`

```
<!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
            destroy-method="close"
            p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
            p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
            p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
            p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
            p:acquireIncrement="5"
            p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
            p:maxPoolSize="100"
            p:maxStatements="50"
            p:minPoolSize="10" />

<!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
            p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

    <bean id="registrationDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.RegistrationDAOimpl" >
  <constructor-arg ref="sessionFactory"/>
 </bean>
```

Now in my spring security i want something like

```
<bean id="customUserDetailsService" class="com.vaannila.service.CustomUserDetailsService" >
     <constructor-arg ref="registrationDAO"/>
     </bean
```

but my registrationDAO is in hibernate-config and when i do that in spring Security it says no bean named registration DAO

Comment: How are you specifying them in your `web.xml`?

Comment: actually i forgot to write hibernate-context file in it . but now its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring supports reading application context across external jars. Simply add "classpath:" prefix to the context file name. Spring will look for it in the whole project.

For instance, if you are creating web application, you might declare your business logic application context like this (web.xml)

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:applicationContext.xml <!-- tell Spring to look for context defined on the classpath -->
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

That way You'll be able to use as many context, as necessary.